# powershell deleting flag dash character when invoking non-powershell exe

Tags: powershell

When I run this code it looks like powershell is deleting -T from the command line and reporting an error... what causes and how to fix this bizarre error in powershell?

```
function x {
    $exe, $exeArgs = $args
    write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan "`n>> $args"
    try {& $exe $exeArgs }
    catch {throw "SCRIPT-ERROR: $_"}
    if ($LASTEXITCODE) {throw "EXE-ERROR"}
}

$dot = get-command dot
if (-not $dot) {
        throw "ERROR: install graphviz"
    }

# DOWNLOAD for graphviz dot command: https://graphviz.org/
x $dot.Source "-Tpng myfile.gv -o myfile.png
### ^^^^ ERROR OCCURS ON THIS LINE
###   powershell deletes -T and 
###   causes command to fail.
```

ERROR:

```
>> C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz\bin\dot.exe -Tpng  myfile.gv -o myfile.png

Format: "png myfile.gv -o myfile.png" not recognized. 

Use one of: bmp canon cmap cmapx cmapx_np dot dot_json emf emfplus eps fig gd gif gv imap imap_np ismap jpe jpeg jpg json json0 metafile mp pdf pic plain plain-ext png pov ps ps2 svg tif tiff tk vml xdot xdot1.2 xdot1.4 xdot_json
EXE-ERROR
At C:\Users\wpmoore\Desktop\a1\VSC_FPGA\trunk\lay\vhdl_sm_extract.ps1:16 char:25
+     if ($LASTEXITCODE) {throw "EXE-ERROR"}
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (EXE-ERROR:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXE-ERROR
```

Comment: As you can clearly see the `-T` is *not* removed, that's just how graphviz is reporting the error. What goes wrong is that the entirety of `-Tpng myfile.gv -o myfile.png` is passed as *one* argument, as indeed you pass a single string, and of course `png myfile.gv <etcetera>` is not a valid format.

Comment: Just removing the quotation should do the trick: `x $dot.Source -Tpng myfile.gv -o myfile.png`. If you have spaces in file names, then you'd quote _individual_ arguments: `x $dot.Source -Tpng 'my file.gv' -o 'my file.png'`

Comment: Is there a way to split the single string of arguments back into individual arguments?  $args -splt "\s+"  really wanted to store all by flags with a single string and split before calling comand.